# I'm working on a chrome extension, with sub menu which has predefined texts, when clicked should automatically paste into editable column

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension, with sub menu which has predefined texts, when clicked should automatically paste into editable column of a webpage, everything is fine, but when clicked the texts are not inserting.

```
 function insertText(text) {
    const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: `
        var activeElement = document.activeElement;
        if (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" || activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
          activeElement.focus();
          var pasteEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
          pasteEvent.initEvent("paste", true, true);
          activeElement.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
        }
      `
    });
  }
});
```

This is the code is used.

Comment: ManifestV3 extensions don't have executeScript in chrome.tabs, it's now in chrome.scripting. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.